# I am using a MacBook Pro and how to type special characters like ~ and ^ in Kali Linux terminal not working

Tags: linux, terminal, kali-linux, macbook-pro, special-characters

I'm running Kali Linux on my Macbook Pro and it is not recognizing my keyboard. I am unable to type special characters like `~` and `ˆ`.

Comment: `~` and `ˆ` are _not_ special characters in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `keyboard-configuration` and reconfigure your keyboard.

```
sudo apt install keyboard-configuration
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

I am surprised a Kali Linux user does not know this - Kali is for professionals, treat yourself to [Devuan](https://www.devuan.org/), much more user friendly.

Comment: thanks actually I have used apt install command and done all that prior to asking a help still not been able to use ~ ^ " ' these unicode characters. I am not an expert but I guess that's how you learn please help me if you can

Comment: “…~ ^ " ' these unicode characters…” These are utterly not unicode characters or special characters in any way. I am very sorry to say this, but if you think those are unicode characters I have no idea how you expect to learn anything about Kali Linux. You are much better off using some basic Linux setup for a while and then go to Kali Linux. Don’t impress yourself with the fact you are using a “hacking” OS; be realistic and _that_ is how you learn.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed not special characters.

you can assign your mac key shortcuts in Kali. IMPORTANT: you need to select your language and keyboard layout correctly first. So example  then under keyboard settings layout choose macbook  if you ar not in the US.

Once done inside your terminal you can customise what keys do what in your prefs of the terminal. Example assign the left/right cmd key or change shortcuts entirely.

I live in the mac eco system running UTM of Kali however I'm starting to get to the point where not sure if I need a VM